# Using JavaScript to remove rows with checked check box

Tags: javascript

Hi I am creating a crud system.. Adding works perfect but i have having trouble with removing the rows. I have added a checkbox and the idea when the remove button is pressed the parent row of clicked boxes disappears.. currently the first li deleted but not the specific checked row. Html id displayed as a loop using blade.

```
const addProperyButton = document.querySelector('a.addProperyButton');
const addProperyInputul = document.querySelector('.addProperyInputul');
const addProperyInput = document.querySelector('.addProperyInput');
const removeProperyButton = document.querySelector('.removeProperyButton');

addProperyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let ul = document.getElementsByClassName('addProperyInputul')[0];
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    li = addProperyInput.cloneNode(true);
    ul.appendChild(li);
});

removeProperyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    let li = document.querySelectorAll('.propertyCheck:checked');
    li = addProperyInput.remove();
});

    <ul class="addProperyInputul">
        <li>
            <div class="addProperyInput">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control pComparrision" id="pComparrision" name="propertyListAssoc[]">
                            <option>No Properties</option>
                            @foreach($properties as $propertyListAssoc)
                                <option value="{{ $propertyListAssoc->id }}">{{ $propertyListAssoc->property_name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control price1" name="currentPrice[]" value="0.00">
                        </div>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control price2" name="priceWithOffer[]" value="0.00">
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input class="propertyCheck" type="checkbox">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
 <a class="removeProperyButton">
    <i class="fa fa-minus fa-1x"></i>
</a>
 <a class="addProperyButton">
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>
</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: querySelector always returns the first found element. You need to use querySelectorAll or getElementsByClassName and loop over the elements instead.

Comment: @baao good point.. however this didnt change anything

Comment: Yeah, then you did it wrong

Comment: @baao i edited the code in the question

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a collection you then need to loop through the collection and test each item

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll returns a collection you then need to loop through the collection traverse up to the parent "row" element and then remove that.

```
removeProperyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    let listOfMatchingElements =  document.querySelectorAll('.propertyCheck:checked');
    for(let i = 0; i < listOfMatchingElements.length; i++) {
      let element = listOfMatchingElements[i];
      let row = /* todo traverse up to parent "row" element */
      row.remove();
    }   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

sorted used jquery and checkboxes.

```
$(".removeProperyButton").on("click", function () {
    $('ul').children('').has('input[name="properyCheck"]:checked').remove()
});
```